# How to configure polling into spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-http, serviceactivator

I have configured polling into my spring boot application but, i am getting below error.

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.()V from class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration.integrationGlobalProperties(IntegrationAutoConfiguration.java:88)

I have added below 2 dependencies.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My code is below :

```
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "channel",
            poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public String foo() {
        System.out.println("test1");
        return "foo";
    }
    
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channel")
    public void handle(String in) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
```

Comment: Include `spring-boot-starter-integration` instead of `spring-integration-core`.

Comment: M.Deinum I already added but getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfigurer
error when i run my application. it is getting stop after some time

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some mess with classpath. You probably use some old Spring Integration version which is not compatible with your Spring Boot version.

Consider to remove the `spring-integration.version` property and fully rely on dependency management from Spring Boot.

To be more precise that `org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties` got `public` constructor in version `5.5` and respective change in the `IntegrationAutoConfiguration` was introduced since Spring Boot `2.5`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/25377.

Both of those versions are EoL already. So, consider to upgrade your project to the latest Spring Boot version and try to rely on its dependency management: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn